How do I restart foreground service to add serviceType when location permission has been granted?
Reference
Problem

Apps should ask for location permissions only when used.
If a foreground service uses location, it must be passed to startForeground().
My app starts startForeground on app start with other permissions.
The user later grants location permission. The foreground service must startForeground() again with the updated serviceType.
There is no documentation provided for correctly restarting a foreground service to update foregroundServiceType in the Android documentation.

Workaround ideas
In the service, I might try to check if it's running, stopForeground(), and stopSelf(), then startForeground. To not have to restart the foreground service needlessly if serviceType hasn't changed, I must read foregroundServiceType (of my running service).
I have serviceInfo.service for my foreground service, but I can't seem to read foregroundServiceType to be able to compare.
I would much rather learn of a proper official way.
Tried: A condition around startForeground based on serviceInfo.
Expected: To be able to read foregroundServiceType from a running foreground service.
Result: Unable to read.
